Any implementation solved the simple url pattern in markdown?
Most of the time I am documenting things, specially APIs or mentioning other documents for advanced developer audiences, I want to show the actual URL and also link to the URL.
Most Markdown implementations force me to use something like
# The verbose state of markdown
Use this URL in client communications: [https://example.com/some_link](https://example.com/some_link)

Of course that allows me to editorialize the displayed URL, such as omiting www or https:// etc. But it's too verbose for too little benefit.
Is there any markdown implementation that standardized a solution for this? I was thinking of
# ideal solution
Use this URL in client communications: [(https://example.com/some_link)]

Note that I am not arguing about the core idea in markdown of adding meaningful text to links! In this case I, the editor, do believe showing the URL is the most meaningful display. I just want to avoid typing it twice :)
Also, i know that some implementation will link loose URLs dropped in the text, but that is neither ideal (hard to infer meaning when processing later, e.g. how do you deal with that loose url in a 404 finder script?), nor portable (how do other implementations handle the _ in the middle of a loose url? does it start to italicize text or not?)

I would suggest taking a look at ReStructuredText & possibly the Python Sphinx documentation tool - Sphinx is very powerful and has the advantage of being able to produce your output documents in multiple formats. Read The Docs directly supports Sphinx.
RST should avoid making a link out of a loose URL in a code block or other "pre-formatted" text.
You can also mix ReStructuredText and Markdown in a single project so as to re-use existing documentation.
Note that while Sphinx was written in & for Python it supports documenting code in a number of languages either directly (C, C++, JavaScript) or via plugins & syntax highlighting for any programming language supported by Pygments.
You can also internationalize your documentation.
